# Is this a bad DynamoDB database schema?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-schema, dynamodb-queries

After a watching a few videos regarding DynamoDB and its best practices, I decided to give it a try; however, I cannot help but feel what I'm doing may be an anti-pattern. As I understand it, the best practice is to leverage as few tables as possible while also taking advantage of GSIs to do some 'heavy' lifting. Unfortunately, I'm working with a use case that doesn't actually have strictly defined access patterns yet since we're still in early development.

Some early access patterns that we may see are:

- Retrieve the number of wins for a particular game: rock paper scissors, boxing, etc. [1 quick lookup]
- Retrieve the amount of coins a user has. [1 quick lookup]
- Retrieve all the items that someone has purchased (don't care about date). [Not sure?]
- Possibly retrieve all the attributes associated with a user (rps wins, box wins, coins, etc). [I genuinely don't know.]

Additionally, there may be 2 operations we will need to complete. For example, if the user wins a particular game they may receive "coins". Effectively, we'll need to add coins to the user "coins" attribute & update their number of wins for the game.

Do you think I should revisit this strategy? Additionally, we'll probably start creating 'logs' associated with various games and each individual play.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designing a DynamoDB data model without fully understanding your applications access patterns *is* the anti-pattern.

Take the time to define your entities (Users, Games, Orders, etc), their relationship to one another and your applications key access patterns.  This can be hard work when you are just getting started, but it's absolutely critical to do this when working with DynamoDB.  How else can we (or you, or anybody) evaluate whether or not you're using DDB correctly?

When I first worked with DDB, I approached the process in a similar way you are describing.  I was used to working with SQL databases, where I could define a few tables and rely on the magic of SQL to support my access patterns as my understanding of the application access patterns evolved.  I quickly realized this was not going to work if I wanted to use DynamoDB!

Instead, I started from the front-end of my application.  I sketched out the different pages in my app and nailed down the most important concepts in my application. Granted, I may not have covered *all* the access patterns in my application, but the exercise certainly nailed down the minimal access patterns I'd need to have a usable app.

If you need to rapidly prototype your application to get a better understanding of your acecss patterns, consider using the skills you and your team already have.  If you already understand data modeling with SQL databses, go with that for now.  You can always revisit DynamoDB once you have a better understanding of your access patterns and determine that your application can benefit from using a NoSQL databse.

Comment: Well said, and I agree. I figured not knowing the access pattern was going to prove difficult for a DynamoDB implementation considering it's all about the access pattern. Thank you for your insight.